# xcode changinging the color of text tableview for each line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

can i change the text color for each line in 1 cell, i know i can make it using custom cells, but i want to know if its possible to do it without making custom cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}



cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do a modulo 2 on the indexPath and check if its 0. if it is, use one color, if not use another as background for example. This way you color every second cell if that is what you intent

Comment: thanks for the respond, but what i need is to change the text color for each line in one cell, not changing the cells background color, example, the cell have three lines of text, i need the first line of text colored black, the 2nd red, the 3rd green.

Comment: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` does not support three different labels. If you wanna have 3 distinct lines of text you probably want to build a custom cell

Comment: but my code works fine and i do have three lines in one cell, so i guess there is no way to do it except with custom cells, thanks anyway :)